# Lombok @Builder inheritance simultaneously working for parent and child

Tags: java, inheritance, builder, lombok

I have read this this post about using lombok `@Bulider` with inheritance https://reinhard.codes/2015/09/16/lomboks-builder-annotation-and-inheritance/
All works good. But in my case I need also use builder for `Parent class`, and this workaround doesn`t work.

I tried add `@Builder` to `Parent class` also but got Compilation failure because `Child class` try to override `builder()` method from Parent.

```
        @AllArgsConstructor
        public class Parent {

            private final long a;
            private final long b;
            private final double c;
        }

        public class Child extends Parent{

            private final long aa;
            private final long bb;
            private final double cc;
            @Builder
            public Child(long a, long b, long c,
                        long aa, long bb, long cc)
                super(a,b,c);
                this.aa = aa;
                this.bb = bb;
                this.cc =cc;
         }
```

I need both case builder like:

```
Parent.builder().a(10).b(20).build();
Child.builder().a(10).aa(20).bb(100).build();
```

Does lombok can handle that case?

Comment: Why don't you provide the actual code?

Comment: My code same to code that describe in post that i mentioned

Answer (score 6):

Lombok try to override `builder()` method from Parent class in Child. 
So I tried to set not default name to builder method.

```
@Builder(builderMethodName = "parentBuilder")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Parent {

    private final long a;
    private final long b;
    private final double c;
}

public class Child extends Parent{

    private final long aa;
    private final long bb;
    private final double cc;

    @Builder(builderMethodName = "childBuilder")
    public Child(long a, long b, long c,
                long aa, long bb, long cc)
        super(a,b,c);
        this.aa = aa;
        this.bb = bb;
        this.cc =cc;
 }
```

That works for me.

Answer (score 4):

Lombok has introduced experimental features with version: 1.18.2 for inheritance issues faced with Builder annotation, and can be resolved with @SuperBuilder annotation as below.

```
@SuperBuilder
public class ParentClass {
    private final String a;
    private final String b;
}

@SuperBuilder
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
    private final String c;
}
```

Now, one can use Builder class as below (that was not possible with @Builder annotation)

```
ChildClass.builder().a("testA").b("testB").c("testC").build();
```